# How to divide screen two equal part vertically in ConstraintLayout in android

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_16"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_12"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_top_log"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_4"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_top_log_p"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView4" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView4">
      // this part we have to divide in two part 

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This my code i want to divide in two part equal part i have tired but it not showing in two part please help me how to divide ConstraintLayout in to two equal part vertically .

Comment: can u please provide image for what kind of view do u want ?

Comment: @PratikFagadiya thanks for looking i am trying to create this ui https://ibb.co/0ssxLPc

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gvujw.png     is it right ?

Comment: yes i want some thing like this but in center one image view with frame if possible Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView4">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/linear2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <!--Do Your Stuff -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/linear1">

        <!--Do Your Stuff-->

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/linear1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/linear2" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Preview**

[image]

You can replace any `view` instead of `LinearLayout` too.

Comment: ok inform if you face any queries

Comment: https://ibb.co/NV6y23j. this is  look like this its fine but i want set full half and half part of both equal view

Comment: set your         `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_height="0dp"` in `ConstraintLayout`